# How to obtain different gabor images from gabor filter banks

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction

I applied gabor filters on face images but I got only one gabor image as output (blue yellow image)

How I can get different gabor filter images from gabor filter banks?

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

**Generally**:

After every Filter operation generate a new image for the result [result1,result2,...] of the Filter operation.
Then, after all Filters are applied you can show the all the results.

Pseudocode:

```
imshow(result1)
imshow(reuslt2)
```

or Save the results in a list:

```
for result in resultList
     imshow result
```

This has nothing to do with Gabor in particular but with how you handle you images.

Answer (score 0):

you know the the response from each gabor filter saved to a cell, like
        responses = cat(1,responses,response); % responses = {};

and the number of responses depend on the scales and frequencies you have e.g if you have two scales and one frequency you wild get only 4 responses and so on. to show each response from a filter do this:
      for i = 1:4 % or 8 ...
        imshow(responses{i});
        pause;
      end